# ReactJS with Flux architecture generating large JS files, what is the best practice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, babeljs, flux

I've started using React with Flux architecture for full functional frontend application, and I really liked approach JSX and Flux , but the main issue is that when I'm building JSX files using `Gulp, Babel and Uglyfy` I'm getting about **1mb minified JS file**, without minified mode it is giving almost **8mb of JS file**. 
And that's not the end !!  for making AJAX requests React don't have built in functionality, so **I need also include jQuery**

I's working well, development process is faster and code is nicer than with other frameworks **thanks to JSX**. *But how to make production files smaller ?* 
I'm including just a few libs `Dispatcher and EventEmmiter` for Flux architecture. So it's not about having unused libs in my code. I think it is because I'm writing JSX and now I have HTML+JS in one single file. 
**What is the best practice to split files or make JS output more smaller ?**

Thanks !

Comment: what you can do is to remove your libs form the minified JS and you can use google cdn to include these libs because some of these libs are already cached in the user browser and you'll reduce your server bandwidth usage

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I saw that there is a little information about using React for different pages, so I learned a lot from [Gulp documentation](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md) and I found a lot of very small JS libraries [MicroJS](http://microjs.com) which could replace `Dispatcher and EventEmmiter` with just a 4-6 KB in size *of course you need to do some manual work with them, but they saving about 20 times in JS file size*.

**Here is my Gulp file** for generating minified react bundle for each page. *I'm using Django for backend*.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var htmlreplace = require('gulp-html-replace');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var browserify = require('gulp-browserify');
var reactify = require('reactify');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var streamify = require('gulp-streamify');
var fs = require("fs");
var rename = require("gulp-rename");

var path = {
  APP_DIR: './apps/*.jsx',
  OUT_DIR: './../static/apps',
};

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';

gulp.task('jsx', function() {

    return gulp.src([path.APP_DIR])
        .pipe(browserify({
            insertGlobals : true,
            debug : true,
            transform: [reactify, babelify.configure({
                presets: ["es2015", "react"]
            })],
        }))
        .pipe(rename({
            extname: ".min.js"
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.OUT_DIR));

});
gulp.task('jsx_min', function() {

    return gulp.src([path.APP_DIR])
        .on('error', function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
        .pipe(browserify({
            insertGlobals : true,
            debug : false,
            transform: [reactify, babelify.configure({
                presets: ["es2015", "react"]
            })],
        }))
        .pipe(streamify(uglify().on('error', function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        })))
        .pipe(rename({
            extname: ".min.js"
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.OUT_DIR));

});


gulp.task('build', ['jsx_min']);

gulp.task('default', ['jsx'], function () {
    return gulp.watch([path.APP_DIR], ['jsx', function () {
        var current_date = new Date();
        var time = current_date.getHours() + ":" + current_date.getMinutes() + ":" + current_date.getSeconds();
        console.log(time, " -> Rebuilding");
    }]);
});
```

Now for each logical page I got about `40KB` minified JS file for handling all JavaScript including AJAX functionality.
So I'm marking my question answered :)

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

There are some steps to reduce production size:

1. Use production version of ReactJS, which includes extra performance optimizations and strips all error messages.
2. You don't have to include the whole jQuery library to just use Ajax, I suggest use other lightweight library for handling ajax only e.g. [reqwest](https://github.com/ded/reqwest) or [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent).
3. When build for production, separate to two js files (or more), usually we will have one file called `vendor.js` for all libraries and `app.js` for just the code we made. This will leverage cache on browser as `vendor.js` won't change much each built.

Comment: cool !  it seems to be a solution in some cases ... but I'm still trying to find better solution than browser caching, I'm also thinking about making server side rendering for rendering JSX files only for specific pages ... is it possible ?

Comment: yes you can, I've read some tutorials about server side rendering, e.g. http://reactjsnews.com/isomorphic-javascript-with-react-node/

Comment: If you switch to Webpack (which better for ReactJS development), here is a tutorial very close to your intent: http://jxnblk.com/writing/posts/static-site-generation-with-react-and-webpack/